# Change how Dolphin looks and behaves (GTK / KDE)

Tags: gnome, kde, gtk, dolphin

I am using KDE Plasma 5 under Arch linux. After using the Gnome environment for testing, my file manager Dolphin is a little confused about what to wear. Now it looks and behaves like under Gnome. For example, I have been using single click to open files and folders. This works fine in file open dialogs but not in Dolphin. Instead, an item is selected (as seen in the picture).

[image: Dolphin pretender]

Here is a screenshot from Dolphin on a different machine:

[image: Dolphin]

As you can see, Dolphin pretender shows plus symbols instead of arrowheads. How can I change this behaviour / look back to the KDE style? Is there a config option (for Dolphin or in general)?